# Add the ".current-menu-item" class to <a> tag?

Tags: php, menus, navigation, walker

I am changing `wp_nav_menu()` to make it a listless navigation menu (i.e., no unordered list or list item tags) Normally the menu `<li>` has the `.current-menu-item` class attached to it when active. But is there a way to give it to the anchor instead?

`<a class="current-menu-item"></a>`

Edit: This is currently what I'm doing to remove the tags... if there's a custom walker solution that would be ideal. I'd prefer not having to resort to using any javascript if possible.

```
$menuParameters = array(
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how exactly are you applying your tweaks.

Comment: I think you'd need to look at a custom Walker for this. Check out the [Nav Menu docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) for starters, and you'll find the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class (whcih you extend to make your custom walker) in `/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`. If that is what you want, update the question and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: The question is what do you want to achieve? Basically you can style your a elements like you want even if wrapped with li tags